# Filehelpers, Super CSV: Is there a Python equivalent?

Tags: python, csv

Are folks just using csv.DictReader to read CSV data into a dictionary and then creating class instances from there or is there some super convenient package similar to the C# and Java libraries mentioned to remove the middleman work?

Filehelpers has been an awesome library to have for my C# work...

Comment: What are you trying to do with the csv data? Dumping it all into a dictionary has fit 90-100% of my use cases so far.

Comment: More or less, load CSV data from an export into class instances without having to write a dict-to-class method in the class -- very lazy.  Hoping to find a bit of abstraction to the task itself but it's obviously not going to stop me if I don't.

Comment: If they all just need read access to the data, check out the [borg pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/). Not an exact fit, but I think that anything you may want will probably end up being too specific to find a library outside what's already on offer.

Comment: @PatternMatching did you end up finding a usefull library? I am struggeling to find a library as powerfull as superCSV in Java to read csv files and validate them against a schema!

Comment: @Benz have a look at the pandas library. By far the best data import tools available in any language that I've used, and not just in the context of CSV data. In particular, have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html.

Comment: @PatternMatching That looks like what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found TabLib quite helpful: http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/